# Erro using groupby with a transform in a column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

Using groupby in a df to transform a column is giving me a diferent result

I have a df like this:

[image]

column data is a float column and group is the categories of my data.

I want to transform my column data stratefy by categories with `.pct_change().rolling(2).sum()`,
like this:

```
df[df.group == 'D'].data.pct_change().rolling(2).sum()
```

That give me:

```
    data
0   NaN
2   NaN
3   -0.604782
5   -0.298356
6   1.036227
8   -0.008092
9   396.681408
16  397.087583
17  -0.427873
23  0.253185
29  0.040770
```

But, when trying to automate things using groupby,
like this:

```
df_modif = pd.concat([df.groupby(by='group').data.pct_change().rolling(2).sum(), df.group], axis=1)
```

That give me:

[image]

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Your first and second images are exactly the same. You haven't posted the output of `df[df.group == 'D'].data.pct_change().rolling(2).sum()`. You should probably assign the result of your `groupby` to a variable (`dfD`) and use `dfD.head()`

Comment: Thanks for the edit and response. I put the output now. I try this suggestion, but the 'dfD.head()' print the dfD.